# How to make the program name appear in the titlebar

Tags: windows-7, windows, title-bar

In the old days the program name used to always appear in the title bar.  How can I get this back on Windows 7?

From time to time I use 3 different browsers IE, Chrome, FF and it would be so much easier to know which is which if the name of the program was in the title bar.

Comment: Do you see only the programm symbols or do you see text as well?

Answer (score 2):

That's completely up to the individual program what to show in the title bar and there's little you can do about it. Especially once a program uses custom UI drawing/controls (like Chrome) you're essentially lost, since you can't even use the Windows API to change the captions (without breaking the overall style of the window).

Comment: In fact, I'd go so far as to say this has always been the case, even in the "old days" (at least Win 3.1).

Comment: Fun fact: I was working at Microsoft when they rolled out IE9 betas internally, with the title missing from the title bar. I pointed out a long list of reasons why this was a terrible idea. I was told I wasn't "the target user". Apparently, the target user doesn't want to know what program they're running or what the title of their web page is. I was also told that IE9 was all about speed, and rending the title bar slowed it down too much. I was not amused by this particular stupidity (rendering text is dirt cheap, perf-wise).

Comment: If you want a modern web browser that displays the title in the title bar like it should be, I recommend Pale Moon. It's a fork of Firefox that reverted all the stupid UI changes, removed some features that basically nobody uses but were disproportionately large, and optimized some defaults. It gets all of Firefox's rendering and security updates, though, and it also has official 64-bit Windows builds. It's compatible with most Firefox extensions and looks the way a browser ought to.